# getElementById retornando null se declarar o script dentro do head

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber o por que quando eu faço um `console.log` no meu main.js, retorna null no console, embora, quando eu declare o `<script>main.js</script>` dentro do body, ele retorna o valor do id que estou procurando. Segue o exemplo com script dentro do head.

```js
(function(win, doc){
    'use strict';

    console.log(document.getElementById('text-link'));

    
})(window, document);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
 <a id="test-link" >text</a>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você colocou o script do body na parte debaixo do "a"?

Comment: Sim. Eu coloquei, e vi que funcionava. Quero entender por que não funciona quando coloco lá no head, abaixo da tag meta.

Comment: é porque o html vai carregando de cima para baixo, então colocando em cima, ele carrega o script, mas o "a" ainda não existe, já que ele esta embaixo, para que o seu script funcione, você tem que colocar algo para ele esperar todo o html carregue.

Comment: Puts, é verdade, esqueci do escopo. Valeu.

Comment: estou finalizando uma resposta para explicar melhor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizei a seguinte instrução:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

});
```

Desta forma, todo o código que se encontra dentro das chaves, só serão executados depois que todo o html já estiver carregado.

> Outro problema que encontrei foi o seguinte no seu código `Javascript`
>   esta escrito *text-link* e no seu `html` esta com o id *test-link*.

Veja um exemplo utilizando o `document.addEventListener`, perceba que o valor retornado não é nulo, enquanto que o código que esta fora do `document.addEventListener` retorna o valor nulo, e perceba que a ordem dos alerts são trocadas, já que o `document.addEventListener` espera que todo o html carregue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
          alert(document.getElementById('test-link'));
      });
    </script>
    <script>
      alert(document.getElementById('test-link'));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <a id="test-link" >text</a>
</body>
</html>
```